# PHP MySql: Insert empty upload value to database

Tags: php, mysql

i upload image and put name in `MySQL` database With this code:

PHP:

```
if (!empty($_FILES["profile_image"])) {

    $output_dir = "/uploads/files/1/avatar/";
    $fileName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $_FILES["profile_image"]["name"]);
    $filenamekey = md5(uniqid($_FILES["profile_image"]["name"], true)); 
    $type = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_image"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$filenamekey.'.'.$type);
    $profile_image      = $filenamekey.'.'.$type;

    } else {

    $profile_image = '';
}
```

HTML:

```
<input name="profile_image" type="file" id="input1" />
```

when I send `empty` input `PHP` code not upload image But insert empty value to database using `md5(uniqid)` like this:

[image]

How do can I fix this problem when I send empty value?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change condition,

```
if (!empty($_FILES["profile_image"])) {
```

with

```
if (!empty($_FILES["profile_image"]["name"])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to your line 5:

```
$filenamekey = !empty($_FILES["profile_image"]["name"]) ? md5(uniqid($_FILES["profile_image"]["name"], true)) : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put following IF condition,

Replace

```
if (!empty($_FILES["profile_image"])) {
```

with

```
if (!empty($_FILES["profile_image"]['name'])) {
```

so now if you cant select file and submit, blank value will be insert in database.